# Returning json encode from PHP and adding to variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a list of objects that I want to add to an already existing list.

The data i currently have is:

```
var sdata = {"10":{"8":["106","22","1","1","0","0"]}};
```

So i do a ajax request like this:

```
var result = ajaxFunction('call.php',hid+','+ps[0]+','+ps[1]);
if(result != false){
document.write(result);
sdata += result; //add to it
}
```

The data returned and assigned to result is:

```
{2: {7:[119, 22, 1, 1, 0, 0]}}
```

But im wondering is:

```
sdata += result;
```

The correct way to add the new data to "sdata"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+=` is used for addition or string concatenation, not for joining two objects. to get `sdata` and `result` together, you loop through `result` and per key, you create a key of the same name in `sdata` to point to the corresponding data in `result`. it's a clearer explanation because JavaScript objects don't copy from one to the other, they just point.

the following code is just a "shallow copy" which copies over only the values of the first level. it also overwrites anything in the first object. you can add conditions to prevent overwriting.

```
for(var key in result){              //loop through new results
    if(result.hasOwnProperty(key){   //if it's an end property, not from prototype
        sdata[key] = result[key]     //put new key to old oject pointing to new set of values
    }
}
```

the end result is like:

```
sdata = {
    "10" : {"8":["106","22","1","1","0","0"]},
    "2" : {7:[119, 22, 1, 1, 0, 0]}
}
```

Comment: how does that add the data of the second key and the 6 values in the array?

Comment: what would happen if the one of the keys already exist, (which is possible).. would it not add the new key... example returned data:

{"10" : {"7":["106","22","1","1","0","0"]}}  OR {"8":{"8":[119, 22, 1, 1, 0, 0]}}

Comment: you will need a recursive copy for that. there are a lot of similar questions here in Stackoverflow that addresses that issue. one of the most popular solutions is J. Resig's jQuery extend

Comment: Yup but i refuse to use libraries ;)

Comment: you can custom build jQuery, or just peer into it's source and see how it's implemented. I've seen people copy extend's implementations.